# Get root descendant element using value of another element

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm trying to get value of one of the descendant elements using value of another element.

Here's how the XML looks:

```
<RateQuoteResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <RateQuote>
    <SERVICEUPGRADES>
      <DELIVERYTIME>Single-hour Window</DELIVERYTIME>
      <SERVICE_TYPE>guaranteed window</SERVICE_TYPE>
      <TOTAL_COST>245.52</TOTAL_COST>
    </SERVICEUPGRADES>
    <SERVICEUPGRADES>
      <DELIVERYTIME>Multi-hour Window</DELIVERYTIME>
      <SERVICE_TYPE>guaranteed window</SERVICE_TYPE>
      <TOTAL_COST>245.52</TOTAL_COST>
    </SERVICEUPGRADES>
    <SERVICEUPGRADES>
      <DELIVERYDAYS>Please Call Customer Service for Available Days and Times</DELIVERYDAYS>
      <DELIVERYTIME>Single or Multi Day Window</DELIVERYTIME>
      <SERVICE_TYPE>guaranteed window</SERVICE_TYPE>
      <TOTAL_COST>130.52</TOTAL_COST>
    </SERVICEUPGRADES>
    <SERVICEUPGRADES>
      <DELIVERYDATE>04/26/2016</DELIVERYDATE>
      <DELIVERYDAYS>1</DELIVERYDAYS>
      <DELIVERYTIME>before 9:00 AM</DELIVERYTIME>
      <SERVICE_TYPE>guaranteed delivery</SERVICE_TYPE>
      <TOTAL_COST>195.52</TOTAL_COST>
    </SERVICEUPGRADES>
    <SERVICEUPGRADES>
      <DELIVERYDATE>04/26/2016</DELIVERYDATE>
      <DELIVERYDAYS>1</DELIVERYDAYS>
      <DELIVERYTIME>before 12:00 PM (noon)</DELIVERYTIME>
      <SERVICE_TYPE>guaranteed delivery</SERVICE_TYPE>
      <TOTAL_COST>160.52</TOTAL_COST>
    </SERVICEUPGRADES>
    <SERVICEUPGRADES>
      <DELIVERYDATE>04/26/2016</DELIVERYDATE>
      <DELIVERYDAYS>1</DELIVERYDAYS>
      <DELIVERYTIME>before 3:30 PM</DELIVERYTIME>
      <SERVICE_TYPE>guaranteed delivery</SERVICE_TYPE>
      <TOTAL_COST>130.52</TOTAL_COST>
    </SERVICEUPGRADES>
    <SERVICEUPGRADES>
      <DELIVERYDATE>04/26/2016</DELIVERYDATE>
      <DELIVERYDAYS>1</DELIVERYDAYS>
      <SERVICE_TYPE>regional delivery</SERVICE_TYPE>
      <TOTAL_COST>95.52</TOTAL_COST>
    </SERVICEUPGRADES>
  </RateQuote>
</RateQuoteResponse>
```

What I'm trying to do is it get value of `TOTAL_COST` node where element is `regional delivery`

The below code works for all rest of the elements:

```
var deliveryTime1 = doc.Root.Descendants("SERVICEUPGRADES").SingleOrDefault(c => (string)c.Element("DELIVERYTIME") == "Single-hour Window");

var deliveryTime2 = doc.Root.Descendants("SERVICEUPGRADES").SingleOrDefault(c => (string)c.Element("DELIVERYTIME") == "Multi-hour Window");

var deliveryTime3 = doc.Root.Descendants("SERVICEUPGRADES").SingleOrDefault(c => (string)c.Element("DELIVERYTIME") == "Single or Multi Day Window");
```

All these work but the below line return null every time even when the node exists and contains elements with values.

```
var deliveryTime7 = doc.Root.Descendants("SERVICEUPGRADES").SingleOrDefault(c => (string)c.Element("SERVICE_TYPE") == "regional delivery");
```

Am I doing something wrong when trying to find this particular element? I have tried adding namespace (something like below) but that didn't work either.

```
var deliveryTime7 = doc.Root.Descendants(ns + "SERVICEUPGRADES").SingleOrDefault(e => (string)e.Element(ns + "SERVICE_TYPE") == "regional delivery");
```

Comment: I tried your code and it works for me.

Comment: @user2574121 Tested your code in it works too : https://dotnetfiddle.net/Wv0vM6 . If you can reproduce the problem in the dotnetfiddle, there is a chance we can help further...

Answer (score 0):

Adding a namespace isn't necessary as your content isn't in a namespace (as far as we can see).  But what you have should work.

The only advice I can give you is be careful when using `SingleOrDefault()` it will throw if there are more than one result, which depending on what service type you query for, might happen.

```
var query =
    from e in doc.Descendants("SERVICEUPGRADES")
    where (string)e.Element("SERVICE_TYPE") == "regional delivery"
    select (decimal)e.Element("TOTAL_COST");
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll make a note of that. The above query didn't yield any results. To me it seems the condition ("SERVICE_TYPE") == "regional delivery" isn't working not sure why. The same works for other nodes like ("DELIVERYTIME") == "Single-hour Window")

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works like a charm. You could also use XPath to get the element you want as follows:

```
string deliveryTotalCost = "//SERVICEUPGRADES[SERVICE_TYPE='regional delivery']/TOTAL_COST";

var cost = doc.XPathSelectElement(deliveryTotalCost);

Console.WriteLine(cost.Value);
```

Which will print `95.52`

I personally think it's more readable especially when the queries get more complex. Linq is very powerful especially for DAL and List operations but for XML parsing I'm not a big fan.

Good luck

Comment: That's strange! I have no idea why it's not working on my end. Just for testing I changed the lookup to Element("TOTAL_COST") == "95.52" and now it find the element correctly. So it's just not working for  Element("SERVICE_TYPE") == "regional delivery"